# Prevent jumping to next row when user hits Enter in RadGridView

Tags: wpf, .net-core, datagrid, telerik, lost-focus

I have a `RadGridView` from Telerik UI for WPF with an editable column. When user edits a cell in that column and hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the same cell in next row in the grid gets focus.

I want the cell that the user just edited to lose focus. How to do this MVVM-style?

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVVM, the problem is View only, so just handle it in View

Answer (score 0):

You can change this behavior by writing a custom keyboard command provider. This provider overrides the default `Enter` press action. It commits the edits and deselects the cellby setting the `SelectedItem` to `null`.

```
public class CustomKeyboardCommandProvider : DefaultKeyboardCommandProvider
{
   private readonly GridViewDataControl _grid;

   public CustomKeyboardCommandProvider(GridViewDataControl grid)
      : base(grid)
   {
      _grid = grid;
   }

   public override IEnumerable<ICommand> ProvideCommandsForKey(Key key)
   {
      var commands = base.ProvideCommandsForKey(key).ToList();

      if (key != Key.Enter)
         return commands;

      commands.Clear();
      commands.Add(RadGridViewCommands.CommitEdit);

      _grid.SelectedItem = null;

      return commands;
   }
}
```

You have to assign the new provider. The easiest way is in code-behind, as it has a constructor parameter.

```
MyRadDataGridView.KeyboardCommandProvider = new CustomKeyboardCommandProvider(TestGridView);
```

Alternatively, create a `TriggerAction<RadGridView>` and attach it to the `Loaded` event of the grid view.

```
public class SetCustomKeyboardCommandProviderAction : TriggerAction<RadGridView>
{
   protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
   {
      AssociatedObject.KeyboardCommandProvider = new CustomKeyboardCommandProvider(AssociatedObject);
   }
}
```

```
<telerik:RadGridView>
   <b:Interaction.Triggers>
      <b:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
         <local:SetCustomKeyboardCommandProviderAction/>
      </b:EventTrigger>
   </b:Interaction.Triggers>
   <!-- ...other definitions. -->
</telerik:RadGridView>
```